# Solr-Sunburnt-Nutch. content field missing in results

Tags: solr, field, sunburnt

Im using solr-sunburnt with django. I have used nutch to crawl and index my site. I copied the nutch schema.xml to solr.

The problem I'm facing is that when I send a query, the results do not have the content field in them.

Results are the same whether I query from sunburnt or directly solr (from browser, :8983/solr/select).

What do i need to do to get content field in my results

P.S. I'm a noob when it comes to searching and solr. :)

Comment: try a `q=*:*` to see everything from SOlr. And do consider indexing stuff yourself, instead of crawling your own site

Comment: An `*:*` query from solr/admin returns all results, but still without the **content** field...

Comment: Well, the command returns each field for each doc (subject to pagination limits). Your `content` field has **not been indexed**. Please troubleshoot why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the hint aitchnyu22.

So the reason the `content` field is not returned in the results; is that it did not get indexed in the first place.

The reason it does not get indexed, is because the **schema.xml** file, that is copied from nutch into solr, has the `stored` parameter of the `content` field set to `false` by default.

Once you change this to `true` and re-index from scratch, the `content` field should appear in your results.

Answer (score 0):

So the field should be

```
<field name="content" type="text" stored="true" indexed="true"/>
```

Has this to be set to true for Nutch, Solr or both?
Of course it should be the same in both locations, but which component does actually use this flag?